# Shippo API - Multipiece shipment returns empty rates_list

Tags: shippo

Attempting to create a multi-piece shipment per https://goshippo.com/docs/multipiece

I'm specifying async = false in my request, but I'm getting back an empty rates_list in the response. EDIT to add that the to and from address I redacted are both valid (home and office) and I've been able to successfully do single-piece test shipments using them before, just not multi-piece ones.

Request payload (I apologize if these are a mess, I can't get SO to format JSON):

`{
            "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",
            "address_from": {
               "object_state":null,
               "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
               "object_source":null,
               "object_created":null,
               "object_updated":null,
               "object_owner":null,
               "name":"REDACTED",
               "company":"REDACTED",
               "street1":"REDACTED",
               "street_no":"",
               "street2":"",
               "city":"REDACTED",
               "state":"REDACTED",
               "zip":"REDACTED",
               "country":"US",
               "phone":"REDACTED",
               "email":"REDACTED",
               "ip":null,
               "metadata":null,
               "is_residential":null,
               "validate":false,
               "object_id":null,
               "object":"unknown"
            },
            "address_to": {
               "object_state":null,
               "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
               "object_source":null,
               "object_created":null,
               "object_updated":null,
               "object_owner":null,
               "name":"Tony Stark",
               "company":"Stark Enterprises",
               "street1":"REDACTED",
               "street_no":null,
               "street2":"",
               "city":"REDACTED",
               "state":"REDACTED",
               "zip":"REDACTED",
               "country":"US",
               "phone":null,
               "email":"REDACTED",
               "ip":null,
               "metadata":null,
               "is_residential":null,
               "validate":false,
               "object_id":null,
               "object":"unknown"
            },
            "parcel": [
               {
                  "object_state":null,
                  "object_created":null,
                  "object_updated":null,
                  "object_owner":null,
                  "length":"20",
                  "width":"20",
                  "height":"20",
                  "distance_unit":"in",
                  "weight":1.5,
                  "mass_unit":"lb",
                  "metadata":null,
                  "object_id":null,
                  "object":"unknown"
               },
               {
                  "object_state":null,
                  "object_created":null,
                  "object_updated":null,
                  "object_owner":null,
                  "length":"20",
                  "width":"20",
                  "height":"20",
                  "distance_unit":"in",
                  "weight":1.5,
                  "mass_unit":"lb",
                  "metadata":null,
                  "object_id":null,
                  "object":"unknown"
               },
               {
                  "object_state":null,
                  "object_created":null,
                  "object_updated":null,
                  "object_owner":null,
                  "length":"20",
                  "width":"20",
                  "height":"20",
                  "distance_unit":"in",
                  "weight":2.6,
                  "mass_unit":"lb",
                  "metadata":null,
                  "object_id":null,
                  "object":"unknown"
               }
            ],
            "async": false
        }`

Response:

`{
   "async":null,
   "object_state":"VALID",
   "object_status":"SUCCESS",
   "object_purpose":"PURCHASE",
   "object_created":"2016-12-13T20:33:20.318Z",
   "object_updated":"2016-12-13T20:33:20.318Z",
   "object_owner":"REDACTED",
   "address_from":"e0633e8c3f3a4a19ba6a83998906da02",
   "address_to":"b48de7caf2624803adba6cac2b10e1f5",
   "address_return":"e0633e8c3f3a4a19ba6a83998906da02",
   "parcel":[
      "ec25a9566fdd47ef9d728307b76eca35",
      "be5e95a487644abd875f6049a32621fc",
      "de942d19ef8046e49011c3b1971c2dc8"
   ],
   "submission_type":"PICKUP",
   "submission_date":"2016-12-13T15:33:18Z",
   "insurance_amount":"0.0",
   "insurance_currency":"USD",
   "extra":{

},
   "customs_declaration":null,
   "reference_1":"",
   "reference_2":"",
   "rates_url":"https://api.goshippo.com/shipments/4f1e4a275ca341dda8cb31eed746720f/rates/",
   "rates_list":[

],
   "metadata":"",
   "messages":[

],
   "object_id":"4f1e4a275ca341dda8cb31eed746720f",
   "object":"unknown"
}`

The rates_url similarly gives no results:

{"count": 0, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": []}

Comment: Oh nevermind. I'm a victim of "test mode" which apparently only supports USPS, which isn't supported for multiple piece shipments per the documentation I linked.

Comment: The Shippo test mode does support all carriers, but you're right that multi-piece shipments are only supported by UPS & FedEx. Shippo doesn't offer built-in UPS/FedEx accounts so you need to add your own UPS/FedEx accounts in test and/or live mode to get rates.

Answer (score 1):

I am a support engineer here at Shippo. I looked up the API call you made to our servers and it looks like the TO and FROM addresses are the same. You're getting a blank response in return because those two fields cannot be the same, even for testing purposes. We're aware that we need to have better error messages and we're working on it. If you get any more errors or blank responses, email support@goshippo.com.

Ben